# How can I recursively verify the permissions within a given subdirectory?

Tags: permissions, unix

I'd like to verify that nothing within /foo/bar is chmod 777.  Or, alternatively, I'd like to make sure that nothing within /foo/bar us owned by user1 or in group1.

Is there any way I can recursively verify the permissions within a given subdirectory to make sure there aren't any security holes?

Notice that I do not want to change all the permissions to something specific, nor do I want to change the owner to something specific, so a recursive chmod or chown won't do it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This will show you anything that matches any of the criteria:

```
find /foo/bar \( -user user1 -o -group group1 -o -perm -777 \) -print
```